# What are some reasons why PHP would not log errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, logging

I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I've configured /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini with the following:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

I have a PHP application that I believe has an error in it.  With those settings and the suspected error, no php_errors.log was created.  So, I created a PHP file with syntax errors.  Still no php_errors.log.  What are some reasons why PHP would not log errors?

Could it be permissions?  I see that /var/log is owned by root:root.  I don't know what owns the php process.  I believe root starts the apache process and then a new starts a new thread using www-data:www-data for serving files.  Would that mean I need to change permissions on the /var/log folder?

Comment: Try putting the log file in the apache log directory /var/log/apache2/php_errors.log, do not change the permissions on the /var/log folder

Comment: Thanks, I changed the error log path as you suggested by I'm still seeing no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should fix you up ;-)

```
touch /var/log/php_errors.log
chown www-data: /var/log/php_errors.log
```